# How to use Javelin missile against players in multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

While playing multiplayer in *CoD:MW3*, I noticed players using Javelin at the very beginning of the match (on the map Bakaara) to get early kills. However, when I tried this, I couldn't get lock on anything.

I know how to use this weapon on aircraft (aim, wait, fire), but I have no idea how to use it against infantry. I found [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3DmP8CQFFo) where a guy does it, but seems like he is aiming nowhere and still, somehow, manages to get a solid lock on a player. What's the trick? How do you use Javelin missile against other players?

In [another video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buKx1mPCzis) it is even more confusing because he aimed underground (I believe map is called Undertown), fired missile up in the air and got Javelin kills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its simple, look down the sites at a piece of land and don't move the crosshairs (like you're looking down a sniper rifle)  The javelin will lock onto that spot (similar to how it locks onto a plane) and once its locked on you can fire raining missle-y death on your opponents

Hope this helps!